# Using if statements with pickled data

Tags: python

I am new to coding, and I just finished watching a video on pickle function. I want to use the pickled data as a float number I could input into my code, but it's spitting out an error listed below.

My code:

```
dataFF = fred.get_series_latest_release("CPIAUCSL")
x = (dataFF.tail(1))

dataXX = fred.get_series_latest_release("STLPPM")
y = (dataXX.tail(1))

if float(x)<=0:
     pickle.dump(y,open("fred.dot","wb"))
e = pickle.load(open("fred.dot","rb"))-5
if y<=e:
     print("hi")
```

My error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/sc/PycharmProjects/fred project/main.py", line 78, in <module>
    if y<=e::
  File "C:\Users\sc\Desktop\vfred\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 1537, in __nonzero__
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Provide a complete and minimal example (what is `x` in your code?) as well as the full error message.

Comment: x is a numerical value(0) as is y (0.8)

Comment: `x` is undefined, `y` is undefined, `f` is undefined, and you are missing a closing parentheses in the call to `f`.

Comment: Also, what are you hoping to accomplish in a broader sense? It doesn't make a lot of sense on its own to read from a file, pickle it, and then immediately unpickle it. Could you provide some context?

Comment: what i'm trying to do is use the pickel'd data and see if y (0)<=e

Comment: The reason I'm pickel'ing it is because the data is data-scraped float value. Once/day it changes which is why I want python to pickle the data before it changes .

Comment: @J.c.0924 Please provide a [mcve]. There are still many undefined things and having their definitions in the comment section won't help. [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69681757/edit) the question to include all important information (as the **full** error stack trace) we need to answer your question.

Comment: You also overwrite your `pickle` module with the return value of `pickle.load()`.

Comment: It seems like `x` is not a `0` at all but a `pandas` `Series`.

Comment: @J.c.0924 Please provide a [mcve]. Especially the **full** error stack trace which tells you exactly which line and which functions caused the error. It's a couple of lines long. And please don't change the error message to another one as it completely changes the question and the answers. Also, make a **complete** example. If I run your code as it is right now, I get many problems that aren't the problem you describe. These include `f` being undefined, a missing parenthesis and missing module.

Comment: That's true. I've done that, but am getting this error still: "ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."

Comment: Okay, I've adjusted the code to include the fredapi code I've used to get x and y

Comment: For context, OP appears to be referring to https://github.com/mortada/fredapi

Comment: I'm sorry, I am new to coding. I'm not sure what stack stack trace is; is it the output the python code comes up with?

Comment: Read about stack traces here: https://realpython.com/python-traceback/

Comment: The full error stack trace is what tell you which line and which functions caused the error. It's a couple of lines long. The error message you've included is a small part of the stack trace, the last line of it. It's usually all the red text that comes out when an error happens.

Comment: Apart from overwriting your `pickle` import - why do you dump the value of `y` and then immediately read it back as a different variable name from the file that you just dumped it to?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/sc/PycharmProjects/fred project/main.py", line 78, in <module>
    if y<=e::
  File "C:\Users\sc\Desktop\vfred\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 1537, in __nonzero__
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Comment: Please put it into the question, not the comment section. Everything that is important for the question, such as code, definitions, description and error messages, should be in the question itself. The comment section is just for discussion.

Comment: Okay, I've tried to take your suggestion of the pickle portion; did I do this okay? Please note that I'm really new to coding

Comment: Done! thanks for suggestion Ted

Comment: Your traceback tells you that the problem lies with `if y <= e` because `y` is a `Series` (not a float) and `e` is a `float`.

Comment: when I print float(e) it gives me the numerical value, but as soon as I put it into an if statement, it gives me the error again.

Comment: remember pickle create DAT file and you gave file name fred.dot instead of fred.dat

Comment: done, but still the same error :_(

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the package you're using from the comments, you can see that `fred.get_series_latest_release()` [`return`](https://github.com/mortada/fredapi/blob/4f2b13568babfa1355b78f5c3c6fbc83acf68256/fredapi/fred.py#L155)s a `pandas` `Series`.

Looking at the `pandas` [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.tail.html#pandas.Series.tail) for `Series.tail()`, you can see it returns the last n rows, also of type `pandas.Series`. You can check this `print(type(x))` or `print(type(y))` immediately after the call.

Since a `Series` can contain an arbitrary amount of rows, calling `float` on one doesn't make much sense, however, if the `Series` is of length 1, `pandas` tries to do the right thing and convert it [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/d1ee9ff6831a2147a820c240542b4fccf4acc6a2/pandas/core/series.py#L184).

One thing that `pandas` does not allow between `Series` is comparison. That is where your error originates.

Here

```
if float(x)<=0:
```

you do the right thing and convert your `Series` of length 1 to a `float` before comparing.

However, here

```
if y<=e:
```

You fail to do the same for `y`.
So if you were to do this

```
if float(y)<=float(e):
```

it should fix your problem.

But the real culprit here is walking around with a `Series` when you need a `float`.
The better thing to do would be to just convert to a `float` immediately.

```
x = float(dataFF.tail(1))
y = float(dataXX.tail(1))
```

That way your comparisons will work without having to worry about converting every time.